# Showing all rows using linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Lets say I have tables

```
Shape
Id     ShapeName
1      Circle
2      Square
3      Triangle
4      Pentagon

ShapeColour
Id     ShapeId   Colour
1      1         Red
2      1         Yellow
3      2         Green
4      3         Blue
5      3         Orange
```

In entity framework I'd have a shape object with ShapeColours list as a property for that shape but what I want is a flattened list as if I was using sql

```
DesiredObject
ShapeId ShapeColourId ShapeName Colour
1       1             Circle    Red
1       2             Circle    Yellow
2       3             Square    Green
3       4             Triangle  Blue
3       5             Triangle  Orange
4       null          Pentagon  null
```

Hope my example is sufficient enough.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you show the code?

Comment: This doesn't show a lot of research.  If you know how to do this in SQL, have you tried searching how to do that using EF? It looks like a simple projection to me.

Comment: Your comments are completely justified and annoyingly I've had a "Blonde" moment. The answers provided are things I already know, do the job and I've been an idiot to forget. Thank you all and in future my question will show more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a double `from` like this;

```
var query= from s in context.Shapes
           from sc in s.ShapeColours.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new {ShapeId=s.Id, 
                       ShapeColourId=sc.Id,
                       ShapeName=s.Name, 
                       Colour=sc.Colour
                      };
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your exact entities I'm guessing you want something like this

```
var results = from shape in db.Shapes
              from colour in shape.ShapeColours.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new
              {
                  shape.ShapeId,
                  colour.ShapeColourId,
                  shape.ShapeName,
                  colour.Colour
              };
```

With EF you can use the navigation properties for tables that are related via a foreign key.  To do a left join you just need to use `DefaultIfEmpty()` on the navigation property collection.

Comment: wasn't sure who was first and your answers were basically the same. As @oct was first in the list I had him as the correct answer but I'd like to thank you for your help too.

Comment: @RobWhite Although you can accept only one answer, you can upvote as many as you wish :)